# Jump to next tabitem by click button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tab in WPF which has two tab items, tab1 and tab2, and tab1 has a button.

My question is, how do I go to tab2 when clicking on the button in tab1.

Comment: Wow down voting a newbie. You guys are miserable.

Answer (score 3):

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="1">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click">clickme</Button>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="2">

  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In your code-behind for button's click handler set the TabItem2 to selected.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  tab2.IsSelected = true;
}
```